# Translation of "composita" to Spanish

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, translation-request, mathematical-spanish

I am studying the paper [Composita and its Properties](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.naturalspublishing.com/files/published/yzmx634l9k644k.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjBrNCnurnzAhXwkWoFHae4CJ0QFnoECAcQAQ&usg=AOvVaw37zqTGnGJoxagvaMFidG6l) by
Vladimir V. Kruchinin and Dmitry V. Kruchinin. When I make my notes, the translation of the word *composita* causes me confusion, since I speak Spanish. Can someone please help me with a proper translation?

Comment: They provide the definition of composita at the beginning of section two. So, it's not a matter of languages.

Comment: The definition is clear to me, but in translation it confuses me with the word "composition".

Comment: their definition does involve the composition of integers. To avoid confusion just think of the word composita in Spanish as its own word. The word composita does not even exist in English.

Comment: Though they think it is Latinate: section 4 uses the plural *compositae*

Comment: Someone with better Latin than me should check this, but I think "composita" is the feminine form of a Latin adjective meaning "collected together". The Latin word "functio" from which our word "function" is derived is feminine. So I think the authors wanted a Latin term that suggested some kind of collected together thing and chose "composita" (rather than "compositus" or "compositum") because the thing they had in mind is a function. So my conclusion supported by @Henry's comment is that it's Latin and doesn't need translating.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, it's a word they adopted/borrowed from Latin (composita the feminine form of compositus, the past participle of "compōnēre", to put together, to build, etc. (see [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compono#Latin); they also use its Latin plural "compositae" later on in the paper, showing it's not the neuter singular that they mean).

So there is no need to translate it, just leave the Latin word. In Spanish the word compositus became compuesto. So the modern feminine form would be "compuesta" if you really wanted one.